# Energy efficient bulb takes a long time to get bright

Tags: light-fixture, energy-efficiency

Ive recently moved into a newly built house (im in the UK).

When I turn my bedroom light on it takes a long time to get up to full brightness which is quite annoying. Ive unscrewed the lightbulb to replace it but it has a fitting ive never seen before.

I want to replace the bulb with one that wont take so long to get bright. Do I have to buy one from the website on the bulb tp24.com, or is this a general fitting?

The bulb has the following on it:

tp24-2315
L1 GLS 15W

240V/50Hz 2700K

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That type of bulb base is called a GU10 and should be widely available at home improvement stores, lighting stores, etc.

That particular bulb is a CFL (compact fluorescent) and the behavior you describe is pretty typical for these bulbs though some are better than others. An incandescent,  halogen or LED bulb will produce light at full intensity almost immediately.  Incandescent being the cheapest and LED the most expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Change brands and styles (bulb to coil).

The base style should be commonly available in Europe. In the US, we're so established on the screw-in type that CFL didn't have much adoption rate till the industry realized that changing out all the fixtures in the nation wasn't going to happen any time soon.

The warmup time is highly variable, but most new ones will come to full brightness fairly quickly. I've seen brands that take 10 minutes to come to full brightness and I've seen brands that are at full brightness within 30 seconds.